# Java REST api Send array using HTTP PUT method

Tags: java, php, json, rest, httpclient

I'm not able to implement an REST API in Java

I've got a working example of a generic implementation using PHP.

How I can implement it in Java using json library and HttpClient (HttpPut request) ?

Here it is the PHP example

```
//DATA TO UPDATE
$postData = array(
    'item'   => array(
        'title'              => 'My title',
        'personal_reference' => 'My personal ref',
        'qty'                => 3,
        'description'        => 'My description'
    )
);


//RESOURCE CALL WITH PUT METHOD
$url = 'https://rest.restserv.com/item/1234?token=MyPersonalToken';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData) );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml_response  = curl_exec($ch);
```

My (not working) approach was this:

```
Map<String,String> dataMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
dataMap.put("title", "some text");
dataMap.put("personal_reference", "my ref");
dataMap.put("qty", "1");
dataMap.put("description", "some desciption text");

String url = "https://rest.restserv.com/item/1234?token=MyPersonalToken";

HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut(url);

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dataMap.entrySet()) {
    builder.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
putRequest.setEntity(builder.build());
response = httpClient.execute(putRequest);
```

thanks and best regards.

**UPDATE**

Now I'm trying with this other approach. The object Map<String,String> dataMap contains all the details of the item to send. Unfortunately i'm still not able to send item details. The request status is 200 and also the response is ok.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut(url);
putRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
JSONArray itemDetails = new JSONArray();                
itemDetails.put(dataMap);               
JSONObject root = new JSONObject().put("item", itemDetails);
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(root.toString(2),  "UTF-8");
System.out.println("ROOT is:::: "+root.toString(2));
putRequest.setEntity(entity);
response = httpClient.execute(putRequest);
```

***root.toString(2)*** result is:

> {"item": [{"title": "My title","personal_reference": "My personal
> ref","qty": "3","description": "My description"}]}

Comment: Hello LightmanX. Please include the error message the java code generates

Comment: I can execute this code without errors, but all values sent are not recognised by the server. In other words I'm not able to pass $postData like object via Java .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM

It seems that payload wasn't correctly formatted and were skipped by the REST server.

SOLUTION

The problem has been solved using kong.unirest.Unirest library.

Bye